# Repository monitoring updates

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, monitoring

I have a large number of repositories which are deployed to production environments (primarily .NET), I am looking at how I can monitor them and flag things like older .NET versions, nuget package updates, database quota usages (MSSQL), SSL certificate expirations etc. Has anyone done anything like this before and is there any way to do this in a automated way, not to fix the issues but flag that they are there for now

Comment: @MickyD - Its to know there are updates there not to automate the updates, I should have been clearer in my post

Comment: @MickyD Apologies, again, I should have been more clear, there I am talking about nuget packages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.